# Obtain length of string in EL

Tags: jsf-2, facelets, el

Can we find the length of a `String` in Facelets page to check for a condition using `<ui:fragment>`?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

If you just need to know if it's empty or null, use [EL](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/el/info) `empty` keyword:

```
<ui:fragment rendered="#{not empty bean.string}">
```

Or if you really need to know its exact length, use [`String#length()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#length%28%29) method directly:

```
<ui:fragment rendered="#{bean.string.length() gt 42}">
```

Or if you aren't on Servlet 3.0 / EL 2.2 yet, use [JSTL](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/jstl/info) [`fn:length()`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/javaserverfaces/2.1/docs/vdldocs/facelets/fn/length.fn.html) function:

```
<ui:fragment rendered="#{fn:length(bean.string) gt 42}">
```

Comment: Thank you BalusC. I replaced size to length. The whole time I was considering it to be a list instead of string.